Formula for limits of indeterminate forms of $1^\infty$
I'm currently learning limits now. I`ve reached the "$1^\infty$" case. During my search for online documents which in some way could help me tackle these limits I found two formulas:

$\lim_{x \to \infty+}f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x \to \infty+}g(x)\ln{f(x)}}$
$\lim_{x \to \infty+}f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x \to \infty+}(f(x)-1)g(x)}$

Where $\lim_{x\to\infty+}f(x)=1$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty+}g(x)=\infty$
I don`t have any problem comprehending the first one, but I can't see the intuition beyond the second one. What is the proof for this? How can it be derived?

Hint: $\log(1+x) \sim x$ when $x\to 0$.

@jjagmath is this a legit justification when it comes to competitions?

That would depend on the competition, I don't know, for example, if the contestants are expected to know the definition of the $\sim$ notation...

@jjagmath and can $f(x)$ be replaced with $f(x)^n$, where $n\in{N*}$? If f(x) approaches one does`nt $f(x)^n$ also?
